# How retrieve a record but only when every linked sub entities column 'archived' is set to true?

Tags: postgresql, jpa, eclipselink

I have entities named Record that are stored in a postgresql table.

Theses records can be archived on backup media.

The assocation is like that : Record <-> AssocationTable <-> Media

A record can be associated with more than 1 media. The association table provide an attribute : archived as boolean

I would like to write a query that return a list of records.
But I want to find a record only when each association to a media have the archived attribute set to true.

Sample :

Media (id, name)
1, First media
2, Second Media

Record (id, name)
10, First record
20, Second record
30, Third record

Association (media id, record id, archived)
1, 10, true
2, 10, false
1, 20, false
1, 30, true
2, 30, true

So, here we have 3 records, record 10 is linked to media 1 and 2, but media 2 is not archived, so I don't want it. Record 20 is only linked to media 1 but not archived, again I don't want it. Then record 30 is linked to media 1 and 2, and are both marked as archived. That's the kind of record I want to find.

I tried something like that :

```
SELECT r FROM Record r, ArchiveMediasRecords ass, AchiveMedia a WHERE ass MEMBER OF r.medias AND ass MEMBER OF a.records AND ass.archived = true
```

But the ass.archived=true is not a criteria that match 'every' associations.

Thanks.

Note : Java 8u51, Eclipselink 2.6 and PostgreSQL 9.4

Edit, using pure SQL gives me this :

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM recorder.records r WHERE true = ALL (
    SELECT archived FROM recorder.archive_medias_records WHERE record_id = r.id
)


Seq Scan on records r  (cost=0.00..6026.82 rows=190 width=182)
  Filter: (SubPlan 1)
  SubPlan 1
    ->  Seq Scan on archive_medias_records  (cost=0.00..31.63 rows=9 width=1)
          Filter: (record_id = r.id)
```

Real data :

Record
    2001;.....
    2002;.....
    2003;.....

Media
    1;"PLop";....
    5;"plip";....

Assocation
    1;2001;TRUE

```
1;2002;TRUE  
5;2002;FALSE  

1;2003;TRUE  
5;2003;TRUE
```

Expected : 
    Record 2001 and 2003

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DDL and sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE media (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT
);
INSERT INTO media VALUES
  (1,'PLop'),
  (5,'plip');

CREATE TABLE record (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT
);
INSERT INTO record VALUES
  (2001,'First record'),
  (2002,'Second record'),
  (2003,'Third record');

CREATE TABLE assosiation(
  mediaid INTEGER REFERENCES media(id),
  recordid INTEGER REFERENCES record(id),
  archived BOOLEAN
);
INSERT INTO assosiation VALUES
  (1,2001,true),
  (1,2002,true),
  (5,2002,false),
  (1,2003,true),
  (5,2003,true);
```

`psql` below returns expected values:

```
SELECT * FROM record r WHERE
true = ALL (
  SELECT archived FROM assosiation WHERE recordid = r.id
);
```

OUTPUT :

```
  id  |     name     
------+--------------
 2001 | First record
 2003 | Third record
(2 rows)
```

Comment: could you please be more specific ? (include error trace / postgesql / jpa version you are using)  @iXô

Comment: in your question you mentioned "..when each association to a media have the archived attribute set to true.." but you have not mentioned that **all association records should be presented**...is it correct what you mean ? @iXô

Comment: Sorry, yes, that's whats I want, I want records when all association are maked as achived = true

Comment: Ok, thanks it works if a record is associated to every media, but if a record is only associated to a subset of media this record can't be returned. Maybe by tweaking the second subselect we can acheive this, any idea ?

Comment: Ok. Please change original question with sample data INPUT and expected OUTPUT @iXô

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry, I have provided sample data and expected output at the end of the original question

Comment: how does it differ from the original answer  ?  @iXô

Comment: It doesn't, the sample was already good, the second one is a real extract from my database

Comment: I don't understand, I am sure your first solution wasn't working for me. But I was doing something wrong, as it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a few ways to do this, but I would try using "ALL" with a subquery:
http://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_04/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_all_any

```
"Select r FROM Record r where true = ALL (Select amr.archived from  ArchiveMediasRecord amr where amr.record = r)"
```

The above query assumes you have a ArchiveMediasRecord.record relationship.  If you don't, then you would need to use member of as you did in the original query.

Comment: It may be the good way to do it, but it doesn't seems to work for me.

Comment: I would just change to the [postgresql documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-subquery.html)

Comment: Tried pure sql : select * from records as r where true = all (select b.archived from archive_medias_records as b where b.record_id = r.id) and this doesn't works either :(

Comment: @iXô _doesn't seems to work_ does not help. How does the result differ from the expected one? Use it to improve the question

Comment: Yes I know that it was the works return, When I say that it doesn't work, I meant that it returns me record with one assocation where archived = false

Comment: Can you detail which rows it is returning and which it is filtering?  You might also show the SQL that is generated so we can tell why your database isn't filtering it as expected.